# How to change the Content-Type response in the REST DataSnap

Tags: json, rest, delphi, indy, datasnap

I have a project made from `WebBroker REST`, running as a service, I need to change the`Cotent-Type` response to `application/json` and by default `WebBroker REST` brings me as a result the

> Content-Type 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'

I change the response by accessing the method

> GetInvocationMetadata(True).ResponseContentType = 'application/json'

of the `Data.DBXPlatform` class, but it still does not resolve it it adds another`Content-Type` just below the current one.

This only happens only in `WebBroker REST`, if I create a project by DataSnap Server I usually get it. But I need `WebBroker REST` to access the information the client sends me.

Example of how to make the problem occur.

- Create a Project from the `DataSnap REST Application`

In the ServerMethods class, do the same model.

```
uses System.StrUtils, Data.DBXPlatform;

function TServerMethods1.EchoString(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := Value;
  GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseContentType := 'application/json';
end;
```

Example response Header.

Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 25
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 16:41:37 GMT
Pragma: dssession=542354.126073.592372,dssessionexpires=1200000
Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 4):

In New DataSnap WebBroker Application Wizard you have the option to create a separate Server Module. In the generated unit WebModuleUnit1.pas there is a variable WebModuleClass, which is a descendant of TWebModule. This WebModuleClass object has a public property Response of type TWebResponse, which gives you ability to set ContentType.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Web.HTTPApp.TWebResponse.ContentType

Comment: I use Delphi XE7, in WebModuleUnit1.pas create function. 

procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleAfterDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Response.ContentType := 'application/json';
end; 

and response header is. 

Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 25
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 16:41:37 GMT
Pragma: dssession=542354.126073.592372,dssessionexpires=1200000

but i need in content-type only application/json, has as?

Comment: Do you have any idea?